# Layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3

Tags: python, keras

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Lambda, Reshape,Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv1D,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D, MaxPooling1D, Reshape
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import random
import numpy as np

window_height = 8
filter_size=window_height
pooling_size = 28
stride_step = 2

def fws():
    input = Input(shape=(5,window_height,1))
    print input.shape
    shared_conv = Conv2D(filters = 1, kernel_size = ((1,window_height,1)))
    output = shared_conv(input)
    print output.shape

fws()
```

i seem to have some problems with the applying the filter onto the data..  I need the filter to slide across the 5 sections of (8,1) with a filter of shape (8,1)...

But are instead getting error message:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3
```

I tried to fix it by adding another number, but this doesn't seem to help as the API says it only requires two numbers.

Comment: You added the extra numner to the `Input` shape, but not to your data. Your data must match exactly the shape you passed to `Input`. --> `(samples, 5, window_height,1)`.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean by that @DanielMöller...

Answer (score 2):

The error message is in a line of code that you didn't put in your question. It's in the `fit` method (or predict, evaluate, etc.).

It says that:

- Your data (numpy array that you don't show in your question) has 3 dimensions.
- But your model expects 4 dimensions, which are `(batchSize, 5, window_height,1)`.

When you define `Input((5,window_height,1))`, the model expects that each sample (each image) has this passed shape, in other words, there is an additional dimension containing samples, which is the batch size. Internally, the input shape is `(None, 5, window_height, 1)`.

You must shape your input data (numpy array) so it matches what you defined in the input layer.

```
reshapedData = X_train.reshape((samples, 5, window_height, 1))
model.fit
```

Also, your `kernel_size` should have only 2 dimensions (you're using a Conv2D). One of those 3 dimensions is the number of channels. The filters will automatically adapt to this number.

Comment: Sorry to say but this is the complete code. You should be able to recreate the same error just by running the code.

Comment: The error I get running your code is about the kernel size (the the end of my answer). Which keras version are you using? `The `kernel_size` argument must be a tuple of 2 integers. Received: (1, 8, 1)`

Comment: Dimension should be (8,1)